# JQuery grid pager not visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a Jquery grid which is formed on a html table.

i have added the required properties for the grid including the pager functionality.I have set my page size to 10.

The page up and page down buttons are no visible.

when i looked closely, i found that it is saying `Page: 1 out of 1`
But in the right corner it again says 1-10 of 257 records.

Here aremy html tags

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tblJQGrid"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

And here is the code for binding the grid.

```
$("#tblJQGrid").jqGrid(
{url: "@Url.Action("GetGeographyBreakUpData", "GeoMap")"+ "?Parameters=" + Params + "",
    datatype: "json",
    //data: { "Parameters": Params },

    mtype: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    colNames: ['Id','GeoGraphy', 'Completed', 'InProgress'],
    colModel: [
    { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 20, stype: 'text',hidden:true },
    { name: 'Geography', index: 'Geography', width: 150 },
    { name: 'Completed', index: 'Completed', width: 150 },
    { name: 'InProgress', index: 'InProgress', width: 150 },
    ],
    pager:'#pager',
    jsonReader: {cell:""},
    rowNum: 10,
    sortorder: "desc",
    sortname: 'Id',
    viewrecords: true,

    caption: "Survey Status:Summary",
    scrollOffset: 0});
    $("#tblJQGrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{search:true});
```

Any suggestion on what i am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: It's important that you write in all question the information about **the version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use) and **the fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). You should include the example of the data  (at least two rows of data) returned from the server (`url`). Probably you don't implemented server side paging. It's not really required with 257 rows of data. You can return *all data* at once and use `loadonce: true, forceClientSorting: true` option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `loadonce: true`, `forceClientSorting: true` option.